# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch2trt.plugins'

Tags: python, import, module

Thanks in advance!

I've installed torch2trt as follows:
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/trt_pose
cd trt_pose
sudo python3 setup.py install

Through a terminal opening python3,i can do the following - HOORAY!

```
import torch2trt
print(torch2trt.__file__)
/home/user/torch2trt/torch2trt/__init__.py
```

However when I run my script which imports torch2trt i get the following message:

```
import torch2trt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch2trt-0.1.0-py3.6.egg/torch2trt/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch2trt-0.1.0-py3.6.egg/torch2trt/__init__.py", line 7, in load_plugins
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch2trt.plugins'
```

Please help my NOOBNESS!

Comment: `/home/user/torch2trt/torch2trt/__init__.py` It looks like you have a local file named `torch2trt`, and the import is finding that file instead of the "real" one in the dist-packages directory.

Comment: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/torch2trt/issues/17

Comment: @JohnGordon - So what would I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Do you, in fact, have a local file or directory named `torch2trt`?  If so, remove it.

Comment: No Joy same error as before but now I also cannot run it from terminal where it was working :(